# FrameLayout overlapping BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout

My app consist of a AppBarLayout at the top, FrameLayout at the middle and a BottomNavigationView at the bottom. At first, the FrameLayout were overlapping both the AppBarLayout and BottomNavigationView. I managed to separate the AppBarLayout and the FrameLayout but can't seem to separate BottomNavigationView away.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jy.hi.Splash"
android:background="@color/whiteBG">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="hi"
                android:textColor="@color/talecolor"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<!--bottom-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavView_Bar"
        android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector">

    </com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

The LinearLayout height is set to `match_parent`.

Change it to `wrap_content`

```
(...)
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
(...)
```